# injectAsync Argument of type 'FunctionWithParamTokens' is not assignable to parameter of type '(done: () => void) => void'

Tags: jasmine, angular

I am trying to unit test by example from:

https://developers.livechatinc.com/blog/testing-angular-2-apps-dependency-injection-and-components/

bit modified:

```
it('should render on id testRenamed', injectAsync(
        [TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
        return tcb.createAsync(TodoItemRenderer)
            .then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture) => {
                const element = componentFixture.nativeElement;
                componentFixture.componentInstance.testRenamed = 'John';
                componentFixture.detectChanges();

                expect(element.getElementById("testRenamed").innerHTML).toEqual('John');

            })
        }));
```

and getting the error - see title.

Also tried to copy test from this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620977/angular2-injectasync-testing

```
it('should be able to get', injectAsync([Http], (http: Http) => {
    return http.get('http://www.google.com')
      .toPromise()
      .then((res: Response) => {
        expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        console.log('RES', res.json());
      }, (err) => {
        expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        console.log('ERR', err);
      })
    .catch((err) => {
        expect(false).toBeTruthy();
        console.log('CATCH', err);
      })
  }));
```

because he does not write that he gets errors, he has different problem. Still I am getting same error.

I see this error in webstorm when I hover with mouse. And also my test is red.

```
TodoItemRenderer should render on id testRenamed
TypeError: queueableFn.fn.call is not a function
TypeError: queueableFn.fn.call is not a function
    at attemptSync (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1886:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1874:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1859:10)
    at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:697:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:359:10)
    at Object.fn (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2479:37)
    at attemptAsync (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1916:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1871:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1859:10)
    at Env.queueRunnerFactory (http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:697:35)
```

When I click on this function definition, I see:

````
/**
 * Allows injecting dependencies in `beforeEach()` and `it()`. The test must return
 * a promise which will resolve when all asynchronous activity is complete.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * ```
 * it('...', injectAsync([AClass], (object) => {
 *   return object.doSomething().then(() => {
 *     expect(...);
 *   });
 * })
 * ```
 *
 * @param {Array} tokens
 * @param {Function} fn
 * @return {FunctionWithParamTokens}
 */
export declare function injectAsync(tokens: any[], fn: Function): FunctionWithParamTokens;
````

What is wrong here?

Comment: You've to import `it` from `angular2/testing`. Angular2 patched most of jasmine functions, you're using the jasmine's one, not angular2's. See [testing.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/testing/testing.ts#L129)

Comment: this works, at least does not throw error. thanks

Comment: injectAsync is deprecated in Beta 16